# Index into vector field in 2 or 3 dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I have `vecfield` which is an `ndarray` with `m` entries for each spatial location in a (discrete) 2 or 3 dimensional space with shape `(w, h)` or `(w, h, d)`. Now I get an `ndarray` with a list of indices `(i, j)` or `(i, j, k)` and I'd like to read the `m` entries corresponding to each index.

Code (for 2D) is probably more helpful:

```
vecfield = np.zeros([w, h, m]) 
fill_me_with_data(vecfield)
idx = generate_indices() 
# idx is now for example ndarray with [[0, 0], [9, 8], [15, 6], [9, 1]]
result = vecfield[idx, :]
# result should now be 4 x m (4 because 'idx' has 4 indices)
```

It seems that idx gets "linearized" and then used as index, so it does not work that way. **How can I achieve what I want?**

Comment: Could you add a sample case and the expected o/p?

Comment: Won't `vecfield[idx[:,0],idx[:,1],:]` for that case?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a read about the way numpy advanced indexing works http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html. I think what you want is:

```
vecfield[zip(idx)]
```

`zip(idx)` returns the list of first components followed by the list of second components, which is what you need to pass for advanced indexing.

Comment: You need to use `*idx` to perform this `zip` transpose.

Comment: Maybe in Python3, not in Python2 as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [258]: vec=np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)
In [263]: idx=np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[3,2]])

In [264]: idx.shape
Out[264]: (3, 2)
In [265]: vec[idx,:].shape
Out[265]: (3, 2, 3, 2)
```

Indexing directly with `idx` effectively replaces that 1st dimension (of size 4) with this (3,2) array.  In other words, it picks `vec[i,:,:]` for all 6 values in `idx`.

What Divakar suggested:

```
In [266]: vec[idx[:,0], idx[:,1],:]
Out[266]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 8,  9],
       [22, 23]])
```

This uses the 1st col of `idx` to index the 1st dimension, and the 2nd column to index the 2nd dimension.

List zip also works, but needs a `*`:

```
In [267]: list(zip(*idx))
Out[267]: [(0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 2)]
In [268]: vec[list(zip(*idx))]
Out[268]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 8,  9],
       [22, 23]])
```

Like the first answer, it indexes the 1st dim with (0,1,3).  It works if `idx` is a list of lists rather than an array.  An array equivalent would be:

```
In [272]: tuple(idx.T)
Out[272]: (array([0, 1, 3]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

In sum, to pick `n` items in 2 dimensions, you need 2 `n` element lists/arrays.